# get scaled width and height of the image using java script?

Tags: javascript, image

i want to get scaled size of an image using javascript.
for example:
original size of a image is 600x600
and by using css i set it to width 100%

so if size of the browser window changes the height and width of the image will be scaled accordingly.

i want to get that scaled height and width of the image.
using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
$("#myImage").height();
$("#myImage").width();
```

Plain Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("myImage").style.offsetHeight;
document.getElementById("myImage").style.offsetWidth;
```

I think `offsetHeight` and `offsetWidth` are appropriate here, feel free to correct me if otherwise.